# Referencing static fields of the subclass of an abstract class in the abstract class's method body

Tags: java

Given the folowing, in pseudocode

```
abstract public class Bug {
    private static int BREEDTIME;

    public void breed() {
    if (this.age % this.BREEDTIME) {
        world.setAt(new this.class(newX, newY, this.world);
    }
    }
}

public class Ant extends Bug {
    private static int BREEDTIME = 3;
}

public class Doodlebug extends Bug {
    private static int BREEDTIME = 8;
}
```

Is there a way to define the breed() method such that it depends on the BREEDTIME of whatever subclass is calling it? Each subclass of `bug` is guaranteed to have BREEDTIME initialized.

Also, Ants should breed other Ants, so the constructor called inside breed() has to be the constructor of the type of the subclass that is calling breed().

Am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: In PHP this is called [*late static binding*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), but it's not available in Java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use an abstract method to do this. Define getBreedTime() as abstract in your superclass and then implemented it in each subclass to return the appropriate constant.

You can't really do what you want using static fields like this.

Comment: That solves the field issue, but not the problem of calling the right constructor new Ant() for Ants, etc.

Comment: Typically you would use a factory for this and define a method like BugFactory.createAnt() which would return the Ant object.

Comment: @AustinYun - You can use a similar factory method defined on the abstract class and implemented in each subclass to instantiate the correct subclass.

Answer (score 0):

It can not be done like this. Static fields are also inherited. Just remove static keyword. If you don't want to double ints then you could create abstract method to getTime or create enum:

```
abstract class Bug {
    private int age;
    public void breed() {
        if (this.age % BREEDTIME.valueOf(this.getClass().getName()).getTime() == 0) {
        }
    }
}

class Ant extends Bug {
}

class Doodlebug extends Bug {
}

enum BREEDTIME {
    Ant(3),
    Doodlebug(8);

    private BREEDTIME(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    private int time;
}
```